# Large polymer web app

Tags: polymer

I am about start a new project. It's a large web application which will be displaying and handling/binding alot of data. I only need to support the latest version of Chrome.

I am conscious of projects I have worked on before that seem to include every library under the sun so I am trying to choose my libraries upfront. So far I have got di.js, RxJS and Polymer. Since I am Chrome-only, I won't be using the polyfill and the Paper-elements seem to be mobile focussed (high margins and padding) so I can't use those either (unless someone can retort this!)

I am trying to find examples of how best to layout a Polymer project for a large project but all the examples I find are for small projects - where can I findan example?

I expect, since its a large SPA, I need to be cautious about what I hold in the DOM, I can't find any examples of how to lazy load something and then get rid of it if the user changes pages....or is this something I should not worry about?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should definitely worry about an approach towards performance, it will not be handled automatically. Here are a few public resources:

https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit - jic you haven't seen it, definitely a good place to start your project from. Provides a good starting point for all the basic items you might want - structure, routing, live reload, build tools, etc.

Also make sure to take a look at https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/polymer-perf.md

https://github.com/ebidel/polymer-gmail - not a large app, but more sophisticated than than the basic examples & as part of the Polymer team he's begun integrating approaches around performance.

It's still kind of the early days around best practices & performance, there will likely be lots of change coming in this area, but this should help you get started today.

On using paper elements, they aren't meant only for mobile as they're following the material design standards, which is a cross device/platform design language. https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#introduction-goals